# Does a browsers' vpn feature securely modify my ipv6 address?

Tags: network, mac-address, ipv6

If I use inbuilt vpn feature of a browser, does it modify my ipv6 address, making me safe as far as my mac address is concerned ?

OS - Ubuntu 16.04. Browser - Opera

Comment: The "VPN" inside Opera browser is essentially a proxy, not a Virtual Private **Network**. It does not change anything on your network configuration, which includes not changing anything regarding IPv6.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Oh, thanks Sir. I guess, I need to manually change my ipv6.